# Updating a SwiftUI View when switching from dial

Tags: swiftui, view, refresh

I have a tab view in my watchOS application which should be updated when I switch the tabs.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabbedView: View {
    @State var d: Date = Date()
    var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(color)
            Text(d.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .complete))
        }
        .onAppear{
            d = Date()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            TabbedView(color: .red)
            TabbedView(color: .green)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Runs fine - but when I switch from the Apple Watch dial back to my app, the view is NOT updated. Any idea how to accomplish this?